# Magento2: How to create a cron Job and make to run daily

Tags: magento2, cron

I have created a Module, Now I wanted that module or controller to run daily once.

I have created below Code.

> \app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\etc\crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_AutoSynch_cronjob" instance="Autosynch\synchProduct\Cron\Test" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

How can I start cron job Manually ?

where can I check that this job is working and can I write any success or error messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it by magento2-module-cron-schedule module.

[magento2-module-cron-schedule](https://github.com/shockwavemk/magento2-module-cron-schedule)

Shows a new Adminhtml menu entry `System > Cronjob > View Cronjob` Configuration.

Comment: I have installed this extension. and ran the  php bin/magento cron:run but my schedule says it missed.

Comment: @JBPakalapati check admin configuration of that module and configure it.

Comment: I have posted another question can, you please check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228480/magento2-cron-job-is-scheduled-but-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

You can run CRON by this command: `php bin/magento cron:run` by terminal or cmd. Even you can configure CRON in server by ssh using `crontab -e` command. Maybe you will need root user of server you can learn about Magento 2 CRON configuration from here : [Magento 2 cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html).
You can check CRON successful run or not from `cron_schedule` database table. You can check CRON status by this command on the server : `sudo service cron status`.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic updating of the cron job timing via the Admin Configuration :

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="my_module" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>My Module</label>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <section id="cron_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Cron Configuration</label>
            <tab>my_module</tab>
            <resource>My_Module::cron</resource>
            <group id="cron_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Cron Timing</label>
                <field id="cron_time" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Cron Job Time</label>
                    <comment>Enter the cron job timing in the format "* * * * *", where each asterisk represents a field for minute, hour, day of the month, month, and day of the week, respectively. For example, "0 3 * * *" represents a cron job that runs every day at 3:00am.</comment>
                    <validate>required-entry cron_expression_validator</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </sections>
</config>
```

In this example, we've added a new section under the my_module tab, with a group for Cron Timing and a field for Cron Job Time.

To retrieve the value of the cron_time field in your crontab.xml file.

```
<group id="hd_group">
    <job name="jobname" instance="filepath" method="execute">
        <config_path>cron_section/cron_group/cron_time</config_path>
    </job>
</group>
```

Thanks !!