# Magento2: CRON Job is scheduled but Not Running

Tags: magento2, controllers, cron

I have created a Cron job followed this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228444/magento2-how-to-create-a-cron-job-and-make-to-run-daily/228452?noredirect=1#comment317779_228452) Installed the Extension and check it from admin back it says the job is pending.  Below is the screenshot and my code in detail, Please let me know if I am doing wrong anywhere.

[image]

All jobs are in a pending state for a very long time.

> app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\etc\corntab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_AutoSynch_cronjob" instance="Autosynch\synchProduct\Page\Service" method="execute">
            <schedule>10 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

I need to run this below Code.

> app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php

```
<?php
namespace Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Service extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            Curl $curl
        ) 
        {

            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          //$url = urlencode($url);  
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         return $response;
        }

        public function myPostCallResponse(){
            $ch = curl_init();
            $url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON";
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=jb1234");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            $resultArray = json_decode($data)->geonames;



            //print_r($data);

            foreach ($resultArray as $key => $value) {
                # code...
                echo " City : ".$value->toponymName.", \n";
            }

            die();
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            //$priceCheck = 'http://alaincopheadofficen-2.fortiddns.com:555/webservices/getupdates.php';

            $priceCheck = 'http://alaincopheadofficen-2.fortiddns.com:555/webservices/getupdates.php';


             $result = $this->getMyCurlResponse($priceCheck);

             $resArray = json_decode($result)->result;

             foreach ($resArray as $key => $value) {
                 # code...
                //echo " SKU: ",$value->sku,", name: ",$value->name,", Price: ",$value->price, ", Qty: ",$value->qty,". \n";

                $product_id = $value->sku; 
                $price = $value->price;
                $qty = $value->qty;
                 echo " \n\n in check for update Method SKU: ", $product_id,", Price: ", $price, ", Qty: ",$qty;
                 $this->updateProduct($product_id, $price, $qty);
             }

        }

        public function updateProduct($product_id, $price, $qty1){

 // echo "in Update Product",$product_id,", price : ",$price, ", Qty : ",$qty1,"";
       ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
       $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
       $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
       $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
       $storeId = '1'; //Store ID
       //$product = $objectManager->get('catalog/product');


       $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
        //$product = $productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product_id);
       $product = $productFactory->create();
       $prduct_id_sku = $product->load($product->getIdBySku($product_id));
       //echo "in Update Product method : ", pro;

       $oldprice = $product->getPrice();
       $productName = $product->getName();

      // echo "Product Name:", $productName, ",\n Product ID:",$product->getId(),", SKU: ",$prduct_id_sku->getSku()," ";

    //   echo ",\n product Quantity: ",$prduct_id_sku->getStockItem();

            // $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
            // echo $stock->getQty();
               $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

               $oldstock = $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId());
         //echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId());//, $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
         //echo $StockState->getStockQty(1);
         //$StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
         //$product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()->suggestQty("101");
         //$Product->

         //$StockState->save();

        // echo " \n Current price is : ", $oldprice;

         if ((($oldprice != $price) || $oldstock != $qty1 ) && $oldstock) {

          $product->setPrice($price); 

         // echo ",\n new price Updated ",$price;   

          if ($oldstock != $qty1) {
            $product->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => $qty1 ));  
            //$product->setStockData(['qty' => $qty1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
        $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $qty1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);

           // echo " \n Updated Stock:";
           // print_r($product->getStockData()['qty']);
          }else{
            //echo " \n oldStock & new stock are equal ".$qty;

          }

          $product->save();


        }else {
          //echo " \n oldprice & new price are equal ".$price;       
        }


        unset($storeIds, $websiteObj, $_websiteId);
        unset($product);



        }
}
```

Comment: have you configured cron on server?

Comment: I don't know this step, Can u Please guide me. @kunj

Comment: I have added answer.

Comment: @JBPakalapati You define instance="Autosynch\synchProduct\Page\Service" but you create Service file in wrong place: "Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service"
So your cron job can not run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You can run CRON by this command: `php bin/magento cron:run` by terminal or cmd. Even you can configure CRON in server by ssh using `crontab -e` command. Maybe you will need root user of server you can learn about Magento 2 CRON configuration from here : [Magento 2 cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html).
You can check CRON successful run or not from `cron_schedule` database table. You can check CRON status by this command on the server : `sudo service cron status`.

Comment: I used this command then `php bin/magento cron:run` I got result as shown in screenshot in question, it creates now corn jobs but these are in pending state for very long time. what should i do now.

Comment: first time it will create cron schedule second time while you run this command it will run your schedule crons.

Comment: Even you get out put like error by `php bin/magento cron:run` this command

Comment: I got this Result when i used that `corn:run` command : `C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE>php bin/magento cron:run
Failed loading c:\xampp\php\ext\xdebug.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Ran jobs by schedule.`

Comment: you have to enable or install `php_interbase.dll` .

Comment: i tried to add this file in `php/ext/` but its not working so i have removed this from `php.ini`

Comment: Is that work after that and maybe you will need to restart xampp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78445/discussion-between-kunj-and-jb-pakalapati).

Answer (score 0):

**Create the cron job**

To create a cron job for the Magento file system owner, enter the following command as a user with root privileges:

```
crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e
```

For example,

```
crontab -u magento_user -e
```

A text editor displays. (You might need to choose a text editor first.)

```
\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log

\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log

\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

where

`<path to php binary>` is the absolute file system path to your PHP binary
`<magento install dir>` is the directory in which you installed the Magento software; for example, /var/www

```
| grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"
```

[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Comment: I tried this is the result i got : `C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE>crontab -u superadmin -e
'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: crontab is not for windows OS

Comment: So, you have to run cron by command.